# How to change background color of image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used the icon from noun project.I need to change the color of the background and it's color also.(change the background color to 'black' and change the image color to white. Is there any css there. or need to photoshop
i have the image in two format .svg and .png

icon location: http://thenounproject.com/term/meditation/29971/

coded like:

```
<img src="/assets/new_home/images/short_desc_icon_yoga.png" height="25px;" width="25px">                    <hr/>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 has a new filter attribute which will only work in webkit browsers

```
img {
     background: #FFF;
     -webkit-filter: invert(100%);  
}
```

It flip the colors.

Comment: Nice answer. However since the image seems to be transparent, we need to apply a background color of `white` to the image to get this to work: `background: #FFF; -webkit-filter: invert(100%);`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap the img element in another, for example a `span`:

```
<span class="imgWrap">
<img src="/assets/new_home/images/short_desc_icon_yoga.png" height="25px;" width="25px">
</span>
```

And add CSS:

```
.imgWrap {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

.imgWrap:hover {
background-color: #000;
}
```